# cross-compiling cannot find -lrospack

Tags: ros, roslib, cross-compiling, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When cross-compiling for the NAO, I get the error cannot find -lrospack.  This also shows up:

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

make[2]: * * * [../lib/libroslib.so] Error 1

make[1]: * * * [CMakeFiles/roslib.dir/all] Error 2

I'm using the process found here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao/Tutorials/Cross-Compiling. Any suggestions?  Thanks

[edit] It happens when I type 'make' in the /media/external/ros/electric/ros directory. I have definitely checked that I have followed all prior steps (multiple checks). I am using ROS electric and the NAO's 1.12 sdk and toolchain.  I have Ubuntu 11.10 installed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12579/cross-compiling-cannot-find--lrospack/) by [dougnets22](https://answers.ros.org/users/1349/dougnets22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-01-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-01-10**:
Please edit this information into your original question to make answering it easier. What OS are you running this on? I'm not sure if NaoQI 1.12 requires any changes or tweaks but I know it works with 1.10.

**Comment by [dougnets22](https://answers.ros.org/users/1349/dougnets22/) on 2012-01-10**:
Thanks for responding AHornung.  It happens when I type 'make' in the /media/external/ros/electric/ros directory.  I have definitely checked that I have followed all prior steps (multiple checks).  I am using ROS electric and the NAO's 1.12 sdk and toolchain.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-01-10**:
At which step does that happen, have you followed all the other steps? What system are you crosscompiling under with which ROS and NAO versions? Please be a little more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, I decided to revert back to an earlier version of the NAO's SDK (1.10.44).  I still get a library error.  And I followed the instructions on the wiki to the letter.  The error that is get is:

/media/external/nao-cross-toolchain-1.10.44/cross/geode/bin/../libexec/gcc/i586-linux/4.3.3/cc1plus: error while loading shared libraries: libmpfr.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

---

Originally posted by [dougnets22](https://answers.ros.org/users/1349/dougnets22/) with karma: 61 on 2012-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Osswald](https://answers.ros.org/users/1042/stefan-osswald/) on 2012-01-11**:
For the libmpfr.so.1 problem, see http://answers.ros.org/question/3531/nao-cross_compilation-libmpfrso1-error